# Facebook Connect api in php

Tags: facebook

HI, I hava a website in php where i have integrated a Facebook Connect API which enabled the Facebook login button.

I login using the button by providing my Facebook credentials. It gets logged in. I can access my profile picture, full name and some other information. But i can't access the user email id i.e. the Facebook user id. I have checked the FBML page [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/#user/groups) but i didn't get any tag that may give me the user id. I guess that Facebook might not allow me to get the id.

Please help me how to get the Facebook user id from the Facabook Connect API.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Facebook uses an numeric increment ID instead of email addresses to uniquely identify each User entity. By Facebook API policies, email addresses are protected to prevent spam and other issues.

In order for an application to get the email addresses of a Facebook User, you will need special permissions from the User. See the API for such permissions.